Range Parameter in R-INLA
Does anybody know what is the prior distribution for the range parameter in R-INLA? In the documentation for penalized prior it mentions:
prior.range
A length 2 vector, with (range0,Prange) specifying that P(ρ < ρ_0)=p_ρ, where ρ is the spatial range of the random field. If Prange is NA, then range0 is used as a fixed range value.
But it does not say which is the prior distribution. Any help?
